# How can I calculate the number of bars in pine script from point A to B?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Below is my part of the code I'm using. I want to calculate the number of bars from p0time to p1time

I tried
`count = ta.barssince(time >= p0time and time <= p1time)`

but that only returns 0

```
p0price = input.price(0, 'a', group='XABC', inline='Start', confirm=true)
p0time = input.time(0, '', group='XABC', inline='Start', confirm=true)
p1price = input.price(0, 'b', group='XABC', inline='(1)', confirm=true)
p1time = input.time(0, '', group='XABC', inline='(1)', confirm=true)


RA = input.float(3, "RA", options=[1, 3, 10])
BS = input.float(0.025, "BS", options=[0.025, 0.050, 0.1, 0.2])
count = 
target = (BS * RA * count) + p0price
p4price = target
```